# How to use mattooltip?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How can I use mattooltip for here? It does not work.

```
 <div class="btn-edit-nounderline" matTooltipClass="custom-tooltip" 
 (click)="edit(row.widgetAccess)"  title=" 
 {{getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)}}">

.custom-tooltip {
background-color:pink;
}
```

in ts file i have:

```
import { MatTooltipModule } from
```

'@angular/material/tooltip/tooltip-module';

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
 
 MatTooltipModule

]
```

})

```
getTitle(editWidgetsNum) {
```

return this.translate.instant('Edit_WidgetsNum', {n:
editWidgetsNum});

}

Comment: Did you already install `Angular material` to your project?

Comment: and also import the module `MatTooltipModule` ?

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: In every component of `Angular material` will told what module you need to imported at the first section of the document like here https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api; By the case you must import `MatTooltipModule` to your `.module.ts` that the `component` that you use `matTooltip` declarered.

Comment: I did,: import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip'; but i seems that it does not read it! Should I add sth in ngmodul?

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-vsoyej?file=demo.medule.ts

Comment: I did , but I am getting error, it even does not compile.. please look at the above code, I have edited that. I am reciveing this : Two incompatible decorators on class     

 15 @NgModule({
    ~~~~~~~~~~~
 16   imports: [
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
125  }
    ~~
126 }
    ~

Answer (score 0):

material tooltips need the matTooltip property set.  It will not work with title.

```html
<button mat-raised-button
        matTooltip="Info about the action"
        aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over">
  Action
</button>
```

[Source](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview)

Comment: but  i need the title.. actually my title is variable: thisis my actual code:  <div class="btn-edit-nounderline" matTooltipClass="custom-tooltip" (click)="edit(row.widgetAccess)"  title="{{getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)}}">

Comment: in that case, you should be able to use: [matTooltip]="getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)"

Comment: <div class="btn-edit-nounderline" matTooltipClass="custom-tooltip" (click)="edit(row.widgetAccess)" matTooltip="getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)">  does not work.

Comment: sorry, [matTooltip] should be in square brackets.  When you put the property in square brackets, it will check the .ts file for the method / variable.

Comment: <div class="btn-edit-nounderline" matTooltipClass="custom-tooltip" (click)="edit(row.widgetAccess)" [matTooltip]="getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)">   and in the ts. file i have : getTitle(editWidgetsNum) {
  return this.translate.instant('Edit_WidgetsNum', {n: editWidgetsNum});
  
 }  but does not work.

Comment: Should I import sth to the ts file, i tried to import import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip'; but it shows that it is not used.

Comment: You shouldn't need to import the MatTooltipModule into the .ts file for the component.  You'd import it if you needed to reference MatTooltip in ts.  In your case, you're only using the directive in html.  Are you getting a specific error?  In the command line, if you navigate to the AppClient folder and run "ng build" Angular will list compile errors

Comment: No, no compile error, when i delete the ngmodule and import line, there is no compile error.. just this line does not work:               <div class="btn-edit-nounderline" matTooltipClass="custom-tooltip" (click)="edit(row.widgetAccess)" [matTooltip]="getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)">  i mean i dont have tooltip .

Answer (score 0):

Try this way `[matTooltip]="PropertyName"` instead of `title="  {{getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)}}"`

Working example is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-2b4fqy?file=main.ts,app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts,app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html,app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.css

Refer below screen shots [HTML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj3di.png)
and [TS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOHgD.png)

Comment: Would you please write the whole line of code? I ma very new in angular, How can I use PropertyName instead of title?

Comment: In  HTML file : <div class="btn-edit-nounderline" matTooltipClass="custom-tooltip" 
 (click)="edit(row.widgetAccess)"  [matTooltip]="tooltipText"> 
In .ts File  this.tooltipText = "getTitle(row.widgetAccess.widgets.length)" inside ngInit block.
For more detail : https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview

Comment: unfortunately my tooltip is not the text, as you see it is variable.

Comment: Please provide code in the answer as formatted text, not as links to screenshots of text or links to other sites where the code resides.

Comment: Plus, please **do not** post code in the comments - edit & update your post instead!